# Custom Filter causes IndexOutOfBoundException in android's listview

Tags: android, custom-adapter

Hello i have tried to override the GetFilter function in my custom adapter class, when the code hit the notifyDataSetChanged(); it produces IndexOutOfBoundException 
Here is the Adapter's Code

```
public class SelectUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserWithCheckbox> implements
    Filterable {
private ArrayList<UserWithCheckbox> UsersLits;
private Context c;
LayoutInflater vi;

public SelectUserAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<UserWithCheckbox> countryList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
    this.UsersLits = new ArrayList<UserWithCheckbox>();
    this.UsersLits.addAll(countryList);
    c = this.getContext();
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView code;
    CheckBox name;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Log.v("Users View", String.valueOf(position));

    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.users_select_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IsSelected);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                UserWithCheckbox User = (UserWithCheckbox) cb.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(
                        c,
                        "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                                + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                User.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
            }
        });
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    UserWithCheckbox User = UsersLits.get(position);
    holder.code.setText(User.getCode());
    // holder.name.setText(User.getName());
    holder.name.setChecked(User.isSelected());
    holder.name.setTag(User);

    return convertView;

}



public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<UserWithCheckbox> FilteredResults = new ArrayList<UserWithCheckbox>();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                for (int index = 0; index < UsersLits.size(); index++) {
                    UserWithCheckbox User = UsersLits.get(index);
                    if (User.code.contains(constraint.toString())) {
                        FilteredResults.add(User);
                    }
                }
                results.values = FilteredResults;
                results.count = FilteredResults.size();
            } else {
                synchronized (UsersLits) {
                    results.values = UsersLits;
                    results.count = UsersLits.size();
                }

            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            UsersLits.clear();

            UsersLits = (ArrayList<UserWithCheckbox>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

    };
}
```

}

And here is the Activity Code:

```
public class SelectUsers extends Activity {
public static SelectUserAdapter dataAdapter = null;
float Long, Lat;
String UID, Radius;
String provider;
ListView listView;
Criteria criteria;
LocationManager locationmanager;
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_users);
    displayListView();
    //dataAdapter.checkButtonClick();
    EditText FilterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FilterSelectUsers);
    FilterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post your error log messages too

Comment: Check out this link , it might help you 
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-custom-layout-filter.html